# Database - Am i doing this right?

Tags: sql, key

I'm trying to make a simple database for a personal project, and I'm not sure whether i'm using Primary Keys properly.

Basically, the database contains users who have votes yes/no on many different items.

```
Example : 
User "JOHN" voted YES on item_1 and item_2, but voted FALSE on item_3. 
User "BOB" voted YES on item_1 and item_6.
User "PAUL" votes NO on item_55 and item_76 and item_45.
```

I want to use the following 3 tables (PK means Primary Key) :

```
1) table_users, which contains the columns "PK_userID" and "name"
2) table_items, which contains the columns "PK_itemID" and "item_name"
3) table_votes, which contains the columns "PK_userID", "PK_itemID", and "vote"
```

and the columns with the same name will be linked

Does it look like a proper way to use primary keys ? (so the table_votes will have two Primary Keys, being linked to the two other tables)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since user can vote for multiple items and multiple users can vote for a single item, you should not create following two primary keys in third table `table_votes`. Just create them as fields otherwise it will restrict you add only a userId or itemId only once. Yep, you should make them **NOT NULL**

```
"PK_userID", "PK_itemID",
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not correct.

There can only be one primary key per table.  You can have other columns with unique indexes that could have been candidate keys, but that's not the primary.

I think you'd have three tables:

```
create table PERSON (
    PERSON_ID int not null identity,
    primary key(PERSON_ID)
);

create table ITEM (
    ITEM_ID int not null identity,
    primary key(ITEM_ID)
);

create table VOTE (
    PERSON_ID int,
    ITEM_ID int,
    primary key(PERSON_ID, ITEM_ID),
    foreign key(PERSON_ID) references PERSON(PERSON_ID),
    foreign key(ITEM_ID) references ITEM(ITEM_ID)
);
```

It's a matter of cardinality.  A person can vote on many items; an item can be voted on by many persons.

```
select p.PERSON_ID, i.ITEM_ID, COUNT(*) as vote_count
from PERSON as p
join VOTE as v
on p.PERSON_ID = v.PERSON_ID
join ITEM as i
on i.ITEM_ID = v.PERSON_ID
group by p.PERSON_ID, i.ITEM_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks reasonable.  However, I would not advise you to name your primary keys with a "PK_" prefix.  This can be confusing, especially because I advise giving foreign keys and primary keys the same name (the relationship is then obvious).  Instead, just name it after the table with `Id` as a suffix.  I would recommend a table structure such as this:

```
create table Users (
     UserId int not null auto_increment primary key,
     Name varchar(255)  -- Note:  you probably want this to be unique
);

create table Items (
     ItemId int not null auto_increment primary key,
     ItemName varchar(255)  -- Note:  you probably want this to be unique
);

create table Votes (
     UserId int not null references Users(UserId),
     ItemId int not null references Items(ItemId),
     Votes int,
     constraint pk_UserId_ItemId primary key (UserId, ItemId)
);
```

Actually, I would be inclined to have an auto-incremented primary key in `Votes`, with `UserId, ItemId` declared as unique.  However, there are good arguments for doing this either way, so that is more a matter of preference.